# sequence converging to p-integrable function

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(f_{n})$ be a sequence of functions converging pointwise to a p-integrable function $f$. If $f_{n}$ tends t0 $f$ in the p-norm, am I right in thinking that this implies $f_{n}$ is p-integrable for all but finite n? Then if $(f_{n})$ is increasing, it is true for all n. I have reasoned it out, I just want ti confirmed I have not made an error.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The $p$-norm is defined for $p$-integrable functions only. To say that $f_{n}$ converges to $f$ in the $p$-norm, you assume that $f_{n}$ is a $p$-integrable function.

Comment: i meant ||$f_{n}-f$||->0

Comment: Then the proof follows from $\| f_{n} \| = \| f_{n} - f + f \| \leq \| f_{n} - f \| + \| f \|$ with $\| f \| < \infty$ by assumption and $\| f_{n} - f \|$ a convergent and therefore bounded sequence, i.e. $\| f_{n} \| \leq M$ for some $M > 0$ and all $n \in N$.

Comment: Ok, so if ||$f_{n}-f$||->0,then $(f_{n})$ is uniformly bounded, provided ||f|| is finite, regardless of what norm ||.|| we are using? Is this correct?  Thanks